# How to INDEX JSON ARRAY stored in own column

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

i have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `datacollector` (
  `id` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `processed` char(1) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  `processed_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `request` json NOT NULL,
  `response` json NOT NULL,
  `response_date` timestamp GENERATED ALWAYS AS (from_unixtime(json_unquote(json_extract(`response`,_utf8mb4'$.date')))) VIRTUAL NULL,
  `sha224` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `available_for` json NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uniq_sha224` (`sha224`),
  KEY `created_at` (`created_at`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `cmoa` (`created_at`,`processed`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,
  KEY `response_date` (`response_date`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

I use a trigger that creates an array of strings in `available_for`. Now i would like to create a Index for `available_for`.

I tried already

```
ALTER TABLE `hwtools`.`datacollector` 
ADD INDEX `available_for_idx` ((CAST(json_unquote(available_for) AS UNSIGNED ARRAY)));
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE `hwtools`.`datacollector` 
ADD INDEX `available_for_idx` ((CAST(available_for AS UNSIGNED ARRAY)));
```

which give me always an error.

The JSON that is stored in `available_for` looks like `'["getUserInfo", "stashClient"]'`.

How can i create now with the last MySQL 8 a correct index?

Thank you for your Input on my problem.

Comment: What is the exact error message? The json values seem to  be strings, not unsigned integers. Why do you use unsigned as the array type?

Comment: Beacuse it was not able to use Varchar...
`13:21:41 ALTER TABLE hwtools.datacollector  ADD INDEX available_for_idx ((CAST(available_for AS VARCHAR(32) ARRAY))) VISIBLE 
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(32) ARRAY))) VISIBLE' at line 2 0.031 sec`

Comment: Also 

`14:39:00 ALTER TABLE hwtools.datacollector  ADD INDEX available_for_idx ((CAST(available_for AS CHAR ARRAY))) VISIBLE Error Code: 1235. This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'CAST-ing data to array of char/binary BLOBs' 0.031 sec`

Comment: You should use char, not varchar, but the 2nd error indicates that your version may not support this feature yet.

Comment: What do you want an index for on a JSON column? Indexing keys makes sense, but indexing documents doesn't. Please include the query you want to optimize.

Comment: @TheImpaler it is for a query like `SELECT BIN_TO_UUID(id) as id, created_at, processed, sha224, available_for, response_date, response FROM datacollector WHERE processed = "N" and JSON_CONTAINS(available_for, "[\"clanWarGetInfo\"]") = 1 order by created_at ASC;` with this INDEX I can filter faster the processes that in the queue for a processor. Every ROW can containing multiple jobs, so my trigger creates `NEW.available_for = json_extract(NEW.request,'$.body.calls[*].name')` and this makes it easy now to select priority jobs with the indexed `available_for`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Multi-Valued Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-multi-valued) are only supported since MySQL 8.0.17 using InnoDB engine.

You also need to watch **what type** you cast the array of. An `unsigned array` is an array of unsigned integers. For an array of strings, use `char(255) array` or similar.

This DDL should work just fine:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `datacollector` (
  `id` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `available_for` json NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY available_for_idx ((CAST(available_for AS char(255) ARRAY)))
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**Edit**: I wanted to add to the explanation. Unlike traditional indexes where there's a single index node per table row, the manual explains:

> *multi-valued indexes* can have multiple index records for a[/every] single data record (N:1).

That was news to me. You learn something new every day.

Comment: Thank you, i missed the `char(255)` thats why it not was working.

Comment: What kind of search do you expect this index will be good for? Apart from strict/identity equality I don't see much use for it.

Comment: @TheImpaler, I think it optimises search even for an single member of the row's indexed array. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#idm45227679283504

Comment: Interesting. . .

Comment: @TheImpaler the reason is that MySQL doesn't directly support arrays storage and indexing. For this reason, a strategy to store arrays is to store them as JSON arrays (documents), and add an MVI for that column.